# How do I use formatJS/CLI with create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app, react-intl, formatjs

Really dumb question - what's the correct glob format? I'm trying to run

```
formatjs extract ./src/**/*.js
```

But it's only going one level deep.

Answer (score 2):

For people who show up at this question:

```
formatjs extract './src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time. If you read this, could you please tell me how you installed formatJS/cli? And also, were you able to run `compile` command? I cannot make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo - I couldn't make it work either! I made a simple [PR](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/pull/1895/commits/6a189980732fc029b6ff074b4bd44465d9a9b942) to fix it (at least on my machine). Looks like the `compile` feature is really new (days old?)